# Java EE 6 - @PreDestroy in ViewScoped & Session beans never called

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, view-scope

As I wrote in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655365/java-ee-6-pessimistic-locking-viewscoped-bean-stateful-bean-with-usertrans) I need to invoke some action when user close or change page. I thought I could use `@PreDestroy` in my view scoped bean, but it is never called (even when session expires). Is this a bug? I use Glassfish 3.1.2.

Any other suggestions how can I call bean method when user leave page? Is javascript `window.onunload` good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the bean is view scoped, it's the container's responsibility to decide *when* to collect and destroy unused resources.

The annotations used for defining a scope indicate how long a managed bean has to survive, but you are not guaranteed about when they'll be destroyed.

As you have suggested, JavaScript can be a solution for your problem. See also this answer: [How to detect unsaved data in form when user leaves the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8259403/870122)